# How to reference the worksheet youre in a sum command

Tags: excel, vba

im using a macro to copy a cell in a different worksheet that I have setup based on the time of day and what day it is. The copy macro im using:

```
Sheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("C7").Copy _
    Destination:=Sheets("Menu").Range("B1")
```

is simple enough. However, the cell that im copying from has a sum formula in it and instead of copying the result of the sum function it is copying the formula itself. Can i use a =sum(Productivity  Tracker!c3:c11) inside of the same worksheet it is referencing?

Comment: Do you want to copy the formula? If not, use `.PasteSpecial` to paste values only

Comment: Perfect thanks. You should add that to an answer so I can vote you up lol.

Comment: I would but the below solution is better ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy the *result* of the formula being used write this:

```
Sheets("Menu").Range("B1").Value = Sheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("C7").Value
```

It's more efficient than copy > paste special

Comment: Oh and thanks for editing my question. I forgot to indent my code.

Comment: Can you add multiple references on the same line or do you have to use different lines for each part. For example, could you copy B1 to C7 AND B2 to C8 on the same line?

Comment: @Gehn47 - Yes. `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C7:C8").Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1:C2").Value` :)

Comment: Ok so it just keeps deleting the cell im trying to copy from?

Comment: @Gehn47 - If you have another question outside the scope of this one, please post a new question.

Comment: Not outside the scope, I added your copy code to my script and when i execute it, it is just deleting the =sum code i have in the reference cell. Its not copying and pasting it.

Comment: Its ok, you guys have given me enough information that I can definitely research on my own and figure out the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Gehn47 - make sure the you are setting the value in the right place. Perhaps you have your sheet references transposed?